# Git: How to enforce a Work Item Linkage Check in Policy in VSTS Git?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I wanted to apply a check in policy in VSTS Git in which whenever a new check in is happening there should be check in policy in which work item linkage is mandatory.

I could not find this functionality in VSTS GIT check in policies, has anyone here done this before, then please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For git, you can use [branch police to check for linked work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies?view=vsts).

[image]

Instead of pushing change to the target branch directly, you can checkout a source branch from the target branch. Make changes on the source branch. When you create a PR to merge the changes from source branch into target branch, the pull request will check the linked work items before merging.

Comment: Is there a way to validate the work item type?