# How to make Related Work Items mandatory when committing to local git repository in Visual Studio 2017 Team Explorer

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017

While working with a **git repository on TFS** in *Visual Studio 2017* I noted that the **Related Work Items** are not **mandatory** (like they were used to be for TFVC) in the Team Explorer Changes window. (and I tend to forget those once in a while....)

***Is there any way we can make these mandatory for the commit?***

We are working with git in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9.16).
And our git repository is on a Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2018 (Version 16.131.28601.4)

There is a related [SO question (50249339)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249339/git-how-to-enforce-a-work-item-linkage-check-in-policy-in-vsts-git) that explains how you can make related work items mandatory for VSTS, and indeed also on our TFS server we can make related items mandatory *on the **remote** repository branch*. However, this has only an effect when pushing the changes, not when committing and actually this makes things even worse... [As I can still commit without related work items (to the local repo) and only when pushing it is suddenly not allowed as related work items are mandatory for the (remote) branch.]

Anybody an idea how I can make it mandatory while **committing** to the local repo?
Is it even possible at all?

Comment: You can't. That's not how Git works. The only place you can enforce linked work items is during a PR. If a PR doesn't have linked work items, they can be added to the PR.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann That was the answer I was looking for. We actually need it during the commit and not the push as the "out-of-the-box" permissions on TFS don't allow a regular user to edit after a commit...  Since you say it can't be done because that's not how git works, I now how some leverage to have those permissions adapted.

Comment: Again, not how Git works. You can't "edit" (amend) a commit without changing the commit SHA, which can be disruptive to others. You can associate commits with PRs instead.